# Adding back ticks to keyboard

Tags: support, ios-app, code-formatting

I spend a lot of time on SE whilst on my phone out and about.

Sometimes I want to use some inline code and I have to go through a rigmarole of clicking <kbd>123</kbd>, then holding the <kbd>'</kbd> and selecting the back tick.

Needless to say this can get tedious.

My suggestion is this, can we have a back tick character on the shortcut bar along with the other editing tools. (We have <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd>, so why not a back tick)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It already exists.

Pressing the <kbd>{ }</kbd> button *with text (that doesn't contain newlines) selected* will wrap that text in backticks (as the same button on the site post editor does).

> [image: codez button]

Comment: The more you know... Thank you:)

Comment: Would this question be tagged [tag:status-completed] or [tag:status-declined] since a shortcut already exists?

Comment: @Steven probably neither and retag as [tag:support] instead

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Only the CMs/devs can use those tags, so... you can try flagging it to see if they want to add a status tag but I wouldn't worry about it.